# How to remove Lombok from Eclipse. Issue related to F11 on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

I uninstalled Lombok from Eclipse as following:

**step 1**: remove Lombok.jar from Eclipse folder

**step 2**: remove 2 line from eclipse.ini

```
-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

**Step 3**: restart Eclipse

**but when I press F11 to run Eclipse Debug, it always shows Lombok Window.**

Anyone knows how I can fix it?

Comment: Presumably, given that it's open source, [the lombok folks do](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues). Did you ask them? They have a public issue tracker: did you post your question there, too?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Lombok added a launch config in my project setting:

**Project => Properties => Run/Debug Setting => remove "Main" launch Configuration**

I removed it. App ran ok with F11 on Eclipse